# Captar el parámetro de búsqueda de una URL en una peticion OAI-PMH

Tags: java, regex, java-8

Estoy tratando de formular una expresión regular para que acepte el caracter `"?"` para lograr captar por URL una peticion [OAI-PMH](https://www.openarchives.org/OAI/openarchivesprotocol.html) (*Open Archives Initiative Protocol for Metadata Harvesting*).

```
package RestFul;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Shift
 */
@Path("{request: request[?]*verb=[ListSets|GetRecord]+}")
public class RestsResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of RestsResource
     */
    public RestsResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String getXml(@PathParam("request") String request) {
        String text="<dato>Not</dato>";
        if (request.equals("request?verb=ListSets")) {
            text = "<dato>ListStes</dato>";
        }
        else if (request.equals("request?verb=GetRecord")) {
            text = "<dato>GetRecord</dato>";
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis del `?` en la expresión regular como `[?]` está bien. El tema es que en la anotación de `@Path()` no se comparan los parámetros de búsqueda (la consulta), [sólo se verifica la ruta](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html).

- <sup>Comentario aparte: Lo que estaba mal como patrón era `[ListSets|GetRecord]+`.

  Debería haber sido `(?:ListSets|GetRecord)`... pero no viene al caso.</sup>

Para asignar un parámetro de búsqueda HTTP a un parámetro de un método, usamos la anotación @QueryParam de [javax.ws.rs.QueryParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html).

```
@Path("/request")
public class RestsResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public RestsResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String getXml(@QueryParam("verb") String verb) {
        //si no coincide con el regex de verbos permitidos, cambiar a "Not"
        if (!verb.matches("ListSets|GetRecord")) {
            verb = "Not";
        }
        return "<dato>" + verb + "</dato>";
    }

}
```

En el método, se asigna el valor a la variable `verb`.

Más información en [*Extracting Request Parameters*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#sthref1537).